# Don't know what the dotted line means

Tags: origin, 3d-cursor

I have a dashed line in my model to "a coordinate origin" or something similar.
Can you describe me what it is?
Is this correct or do I need to move the point in my model?
How can I move it?

[image]

Model:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a line indicating a Parent-Child relationship between the armature and the selected mesh. You can remove it by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> but in this case mesh will not follow the armature, that's moved in Object mode.

Comment: The position of the point is then probably irrelevant?

Comment: This is the center of armature that you have created